# Compact closure in $C([0,2])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

a) Does the closure of $\left\{f_n(x)=\sin(x^n):n=1,2,3\dots\right\}$ form the a compact subset of $C([0,2])?$

b) Does the closure of $\left\{f_n(x)=\sin(x^\frac1n):n=1,2,3\dots\right\}$ form the a compact subset of $C([0,2])?$

I think yes for a) because it is uniformly bounded and for equicontinuous
$$\begin{align}|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|&=|\sin(x^n)-\sin(y^n)|\\
&\le|x^n-y^n|\\&=|x-y||x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1}|\\
&\le M|x-y|\lt \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Isn't it correct? please, if I'm wrong then correct me.

I think b) is not true but i don't have right counterexample.

Your help will be appreciated..

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by:$\{f_n(x)=\sin(x^n):n=1,2,3,\dots,\}$. Given that you tagged with functional analysis, do you mean $([0,2])$ to be some function space - say,  $C^0([0,2])$?

Comment: these are functions defined on $[0,2]$. This is problem related to Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: Any functions in $[0,2]$?

Comment: The function is defined, right? $f_n(x)=sin(x^n)$ where $x$ is from $[0,2]$. This question was in qualifying exam and i copied whole the question

Comment: The way you’ve stated your problem, your sets do not seem to be subsets of $[0,2]$ at all. Unless “$([0,2])$” means something I’m not expecting.

Comment: You probably want to consider the functions to be in $C[0,2]$, but maybe you want $L^{2}[0,2]$. It's not quite clear to us, and compact implies a topology of some kind; so we're missing critical details.

Comment: I'm sorry yes you are correct i edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fact:** the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

The problem is that the constant $M$ depends on $n$. If $f_{n_k}$ is a uniformly convergent subsequence, then for any $a\in [0,1)$, we have $f_{n_k}(a)\to 0$ while $f_{n_k}(1)=\sin(1)$. We conclude that the potential limit function is not continuous, hence from the "fact" we reach a contradiction.

For b), the only candidate is the function which takes the value $\sin(1)$ for $a\in (0,2]$ and $0$ at $0$, which is not continuous.